# .height/width of div returning different values into canvas

Tags: html, height, width, html5-canvas

Above is a test website I'm trying out the new HTMl5 canvas tag. I've stripped it down a bit just to make the relevant code easier to locate.

The issue I'm having is when setting the width and height of the canvas the values I'm getting back with the .height and .width methods are larger than the div I'm trying to get them from causing the canvas to overrun the encapsulating div.

Link to JSbin:

http://jsbin.com/ejivux/13/edit

Code just incase people want it in here:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">

     <div id="leftColumn">

        text

      </div>

      <div id="rightColumn">

      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
canvas{
  border-width:5px;
  border-style:solid;
}

html{
  height:99%;
  background-color:red;
}

body{
  height:99%;
  background-color:blue;
}

#container{
  background-color:yellow;
  min-width:976px;
  min-height:99%;
  height:100%;
}

#leftColumn{
  background-color:pink;
  width:50%;
  min-height:100%;
  height:100;
  float:left;
}

#rightColumn{
  background-color:green;
  width:50%;
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}
```

JS:

```
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('rightColumn');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', $('#rightColumn').width());
canvas.setAttribute('height', $('#rightColumn').height());
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `canvas` has a 5px border:

```
canvas{
  border-width:5px;
  border-style:solid;
}
```

So if you set the `width` of the canvas to that of the containing `div` I would expect the overall width of the `canvas` to be 10px more than the `div` because of the border on both sides.  Try [this](http://jsbin.com/ecevek/1/edit):

```
canvas.setAttribute('width', $('#canvasDiv').width()-10);
canvas.setAttribute('height', $('#canvasDiv').height()-10);
```

Comment: You know when you have one of those days... where you stare at a screen for hours and something basic escapes you?... this is one of those days. Thanks for making me feel like an idiot ^^